# File handling in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to access the csv file which i passed in my form and saved in media directory.
I am able to access the file if i manually enter the path(localhost://8000/media/1.csv)
but it throws an error saying "No such file or directory" when accessing from open function.

```
def home(request):
print("Rendering Home...")
if request.method == "POST":
    uploaded_file = request.FILES['csvFile']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    name = fs.save(uploaded_file.name,uploaded_file)
    url = fs.url(name)
    csv_fp = open(f'{url}', 'r')  //ERROR:"No such file or dir media/1.csv"
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_fp)
    headers = [col for col in reader.fieldnames]
    out = [row for row in reader]
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'data' : out, 'headers' : headers})
return  render(request,"home.html")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried .path instead of .name

file = open(filename.path' 'rb').read()

Comment: I just tried it returns object has no attribute path. 
edit:- fs.save takes two arguments name of the file and file so it dosen't make sense why you are asking to  try .path

Comment: Thank you so much for helping problem was indeed related to path i have posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the path being given to open function

```
csv_fp = default_storage.open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, name), 'r')
```

simply did the trick  :)